# Naming a Docker container with Dockerrun.aws.json and Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm in need to executing a post-deployment script on an EB app.  I need to execute commands on a Docker container within a multi-container Docker environment.  The issue is that the Docker containers get assigned a random hash for the container name.

I've searched around and cannot seem to locate any information on how you might assign a name to a Docker container during the build and setup process with EB.

Does anyone have any insights into this?  I know with docker-compose this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you name containers within `Dockerrun.aws.json`, beanstalk still names them with a specific hash containing environment name and other stuff like that. But it has name from the file above in it as well.

```
8a18a679564e   XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/XXX:1.0.0-nginx   "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   13 hours ago        Up 13 hours         0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   ecs-awseb-test-rcbdaytu5h-6-nginx-e6a58fe786d9eae7dc01
```

The very last column contains hash we're speaking of. If you're creating post-deployment script, you can still get container ID with, let's say,

```
docker ps -qf name=nginx
```

which returns container ID based on name part.

I would do something like this in my config file in `.ebextensions`

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_do_something_on_container.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      MY_CONTAINER=$(docker ps -qf name=nginx)
      docker exec $MY_CONTAINER my command
```

Hope it gives you any idea on how to solve your problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Naming the container can be done using the Docker.aws.json file see the

```
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "php-app",
      "image": "php:fpm",
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "Container",
          "value": "PHP"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "php-app",
          "containerPath": "/var/www/html",
          "readOnly": true
        }
      ]
    }
```

This is an example from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun

**You can name the container in similar way**

Comment: I recently tried that, but when running `docker ps`, the name of the container is still a hash.